# How to play a song using service?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media

I want to know, how to run a song in a service, I also want to use .aidl file to expose clients the interface.

Comment: this may help you :http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html

Comment: All you need is available in `samples` directory of Android SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound basic for Android..

I recommended you for go through this tutorial [MusicDroid - Audio Player Part](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-i).

There are three parts of these tutorial. Its nicely describe for how to implement Audio player for android using service and AIDL.

Also look at this android developer tutorial [Media Playback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

I think this will help you a lot..!

Comment: nice tutorial, as its too long.. i'll go through ! thank you :)

Comment: i am not able to prepare the player asyn in using service ? why is so ? i am not getting a call back in the on prepared listener

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know how to create a service, I did something before similar

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

private void play() {
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getSongUrl());
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}
```

when interact with UI, send Intent from the UI to the service so that you can do let pause:

```
mMediaPlayer.pause();
```

or seek to certain time:

```
mMediaPlayer.seekTo((int) (to * mMediaPlayer.getDuration()));
```

and remember make sure call the release()

Please check the class here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html